# Automated way to see Queries in all Oracle Connectors of all jobs in datastage

Tags: datastage

Is there a way to see all the queries that are there in my Oracle COnnector stages of my datastage project? I am using DS 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No not natively. You could export your project and parse the export for all of the SQL staments (this could be done by a DataStage job of cause)  or you might be able to query it if you have IGC Information Governance Catalog) in place.

Comment: Can't I use the Universe stage? I am able to get the Oracle Variant in all oracle stages but now looking for some specific value in all my queries of Oracle Connectors .